# KeyNotFound Exception when calling Html.ValidationSummary() dynamically through helper method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, keynotfoundexception

I have a Helper Method in my View which renders the whole form dynamically. Now i want to add a support for Client Validation as available in Asp.Net MVC RC 2.

Following is the code i use to render Validation Summary field onto the Form.

```
_viewPage.Html.EnableClientValidation();
        MvcHtmlString validationSummary = _viewPage.Html.ValidationSummary("There are errors on this form. Please contact your administrator.");
        if (validationSummary != null && validationSummary.ToString() != "")
            Response.Write(validationSummary.ToString());
```

When code reaches this point i get following error.

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
```

Message="The given key was not present in the dictionary."
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Boolean excludePropertyErrors, String message, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String message, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
       at Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX.Helper.FormGenerator.GenerateFormValidation() in D:\EBS\Project.Fusion\Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX\Helper\FormGenerator.cs:line 88
       at Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX.Helper.FormGenerator.GenerateForm() in D:\EBS\Project.Fusion\Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX\Helper\FormGenerator.cs:line 70
       at Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX.Helper.FormGenerator.RenderForm(ViewPage viewPage) in D:\EBS\Project.Fusion\Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX\Helper\FormGenerator.cs:line 60
       at ASP.views_shared_autoview_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\EBS\Project.Fusion\Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX\Views\Shared\AutoView.aspx:line 7
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at ASP.views_shared_fusion_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\EBS\Project.Fusion\Fusion.UI.MvcWebUX\Views\Shared\Fusion.Master:line 74
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:

I have struggling with this for few hours. Can anyone help me to solve it and tell me why would this be happening.

Comment: I have found the problem to it.

I had been setting EnableClientValidation after writing BeginForm.

Just write _viewPage.Html.EnableClientValidation(); before anything on the Form and the error was solved.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've come here twice for the solution, so I'll also answer with another thing that can cause this.

In MVC2 RC (I believe; the version delivered with 2010 RC), you can cause this exception when calling `EnableClientValidation`:

```
<%-- This is the proper way to call these two methods --%>
<% Html.ValidationSummary(); %>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

This way will cause the exception:

```
<%-- Side effects of calling ECV first will result in the exception --%>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% Html.ValidationSummary(); %>
```

Pretty crappy to have side effects crop up from a couple disconnected method calls like this.  Kinda reminds me of global variables.

Comment: or if you enable clientside validation in your master page, `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` after `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem to it. I had been setting EnableClientValidation after writing BeginForm. Just write _viewPage.Html.EnableClientValidation(); before anything on the Form and the error was solved. Thanks,

Comment: That's not the solution for everyone, however.